# How do I connect VOIP service to PSTN?

Tags: networking, voip

I am planning on making a VOIP network for myself that will use a server running Asterisk. I'd like to be able to interface my Asterisk server with a 'regular' POTS/PSTN phone line to allow me to call outside my own network as well as for people to call in

I've heard I can use a FXO gateway which is a physical device that acts as a bridge between my network and the PTSN. Is that what I need, and what should I look for in one? And how would I set this up?

Comment: VOIP gateways aren't very complicated or expensive; I'd recommend downloading the manual for one and reading it. E.g. https://www.grandstream.com/hubfs/Product_Documentation/gxw410x_usermanual_english.pdf

Comment: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281112/community-for-voip-telephony It is possible that the SE network doesn't really have a good place to ask this question https://www.reddit.com/r/VOIP/

Comment: @Gantendo In my opinion, when you get an answer on SE, it’s usually better than everywhere else. SE is so picky though. What if we made a phone system SE site?

Comment: @Gantendo Reddit is also kind of dumb because it won’t let you know before posting if you have enough karma. If you don’t have enough karma, are you supposed to make up questions in r/askreddit so you get enough karma?

Comment: I am struggling to make sense of `I ams I can use `

Comment: You need to break up your question.  To ask for recommendations on a FXO gateway, you can try "Hardware Recommendations site"

Comment: @RohitGupta Well I know which one to buy, I just want to know what I have to do after I buy one. I think I‘ve figured it out now, but whatever

Comment: @RohitGupta - That looks like a typo from JourneymanGeek's edit. the original was "I *heard* I can use...". I've reverted that line.

Comment: Note this question is being [discussed on Meta](https://meta.superuser.com/q/15132/107240) in regards to its on-topicness